# Programmatic cost for each purchase

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, while-loop

I'm currently trying to identify which purchase is costing our company more than 40. Each purchase is an array of data I get through an API, and the cost is pulled from a mysql database. I have been trying with a while and a for each loop but after multiple attempt I think using one loop will be the best for performance and accuracy.

`$result` is the MYSQL data, and `$json_array` contains the API data. I would like to join the 2 data sets within a loop so I can identify the `purchase_id` for any purchase that costing us more than 40.

Any help much appreciated!

I have already tried 2 different loops but it won't work. It needs to be in one loop instead of 2.

```
//Getting the MySQL Results
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

//Creating empty array
$overspend = array();

//Starting the loop
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //If the cost if more than 40 continue
        if($row["cost"] > 40){


             array_push($overspend, $row['purchase_id'] );

                if (in_array($json_array, $overspend)){

                        $count = array_count_values($json_array);

                        ${'_'.$row['purchase_id'].'_l'} = $count[$row['purchase_id']];

                        ${'_'.$row['purchase_id']} = $row['cost'];

                        if((${'_'.$row['purchase_id']}/${'_'.$row['purchase_id'].'_l'}) > 40){
                            echo ${'_'.$row['purchase_id']};
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting any error messages, I am just not getting the result expected. The expected result should be the keyword id.

Comment: If cost is just a field in the db. why not just add that to your sql?

Comment: ^^ That does seem like the obvious answer ^^

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code. You're using both styles here inconsistently.

Comment: It sounds like you need a `WHERE` condition that does the filtering in the database.